# Drush Not detect Database connection

Tags: 8, drush

I'm using Acquia DevDesktop application on Mac, I installed a new website on that , everything seems Ok but when I got to the installed path and try to update Drupal core with `drush up` faced with

```
➜  thunder-8.x-1.0-core drush up
Command pm-update needs a higher bootstrap level to run - you will need to invoke drush from a more functional Drupal         [error]
environment to run this command.
The drush command 'up' could not be executed.                                                                                 [error]
Drush was not able to start (bootstrap) the Drupal database.                                                                  [error]
Hint: This may occur when Drush is trying to:
 * bootstrap a site that has not been installed or does not have a configured database. In this case you can select another
site with a working database setup by specifying the URI to use with the --uri parameter on the command line. See `drush topic
docs-aliases` for details.
 * connect the database through a socket. The socket file may be wrong or the php-cli may have no access to it in a jailed
shell. See http://drupal.org/node/1428638 for details.

Drush was attempting to connect to:
 Drupal version         :  8.2.5
 Site URI               :  http://default
 PHP executable         :  /usr/bin/php
 PHP configuration      :
 PHP OS                 :  Darwin
 Drush script           :  /Users/yms/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php
 Drush version          :  8.1.10
 Drush temp directory   :  /tmp
 Drush configuration    :
 Drush alias files      :
 Drupal root            :  /Users/yms/Sites/devdesktop/thunder-8.x-1.0-core
 Drupal Settings File   :  sites/default/settings.php
 Site path              :  sites/default
```

**In the issues reported I found about this problem, adding Mysql path to PATH resolve the problem, but in my case when I type `mysql` on command prompt it works correct and that means The mysql path is added to PATH. but I don't know why Drush couldn't find the database connection.**

**Also in my connection to db Acquia used 127.0.0.1 So changing localhost to 127.0.0.1 is not the solution**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After wasting a few hours I resolve it with adding `driver` property to `$databases` in `settings.php` .

```
$databases['default']['default'] = array (
  'database' => 'XXX',
  'username' => 'XXXX',
  'password' => 'XXX',
  'prefix' => '',
  'host' => '127.0.0.1',
  'port' => '33067',
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'namespace' => 'Drupal\\Core\\Database\\Driver\\mysql', 
);
```

I hope this could save another guys time in future in the same problem.

Comment: If you end up here and DO have driver specified, you should also check the other things defined here.  Drush will choke is 'localhost' is defined as the `host` in some cases.  Try switching to an IP address.

Comment: Thanks @WestonWedding, changing the `host` to IP did it for me.

Answer (score 2):

Using Acquia DevDesktop application on Mac OS, drush could not find  database settings. My solution was to comment out `<DDSETTINGS>` and copy the connection details directly into `settings.php` :

```
// <DDSETTINGS>
// Please don't edit anything between <DDSETTINGS> tags.
// This section is autogenerated by Acquia Dev Desktop.
// if (isset($_SERVER['DEVDESKTOP_DRUPAL_SETTINGS_DIR']) && file_exists($_SERVER['DEVDESKTOP_DRUPAL_SETTINGS_DIR'] . '/loc_1sexshop2018_dd.inc')) {
//   require $_SERVER['DEVDESKTOP_DRUPAL_SETTINGS_DIR'] . '/loc_mysite_dd.inc';
// }
// </DDSETTINGS>

// DDSettings
// Copied from $_SERVER['DEVDESKTOP_DRUPAL_SETTINGS_DIR'] . '/loc_mysite_dd.inc' in order to work with drush
$databases['default']['default'] = array(
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'database' => 'mydb',
  'username' => 'drupaluser',
  'password' => '',
  'host' => '127.0.0.1',
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'port' => 33067 );

if (empty($config_directories['active']))
  $config_directories['active'] = "sites/default/files/config_...my_config.../active";
if (empty($config_directories['staging']))
  $config_directories['staging'] = "sites/default/files/config_...my_config.../staging";

if (empty($settings['hash_salt']))
    $settings['hash_salt'] = '...myhash...';
// /DDSettings
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to give root path and URI in your drush command

e.g

```
`drush --root=/path/to/drupal-installation --uri=youdomain.com <command>`
```